# Adjust leaflet routing machine draw (animate) route speed

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, open-source-gis, animation, open-source-routing-machine

I use leaflet routing machine and it's working fine with me.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
          crossorigin="" />

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
            crossorigin=""></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>

    <style>
        #mapid {
            height: 480px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <div id="distancetravelled"></div>

    <script>
        // set map view to a specefic lat, long in Egypt
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([30.026300, 31.496773], 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);

        var control = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
                L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
            ],
            routeWhileDragging: true
        }).addTo(mymap);

        console.log(control);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It draws the line immediately after I load the map, but I want it to draw the line slowly like this sample for example
[image]

Comment: Can you also show the current speed you are experiencing as well as in the example above?

Comment: This example is just an image to show the result I hope.
It's called Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim but it draws poly lines not on roads, and leaflet routing machine draws on road, so I want it with leaflet routing machine.

If you are interisted in Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim you can find a full example at this url
https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim

Comment: What about the line that loads on your map as you mentioned ? "I use leaflet routing machine and it's working fine with me.

It draws the line immediately after I load the map, "

Comment: I edited the question and added image to demonstrate result of the leaflet routing machine.

Comment: Which version of leaflet are you using?

Comment: version 1.2.0 and I have posted my code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this animation using only CSS. See the following tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/#article-header-id-7 (Note: the tutorial covers other interesting line animations as well!)

First of all add the class `.animate` to the routing line:

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ],
    lineOptions: {
        styles: [{className: 'animate'}] // Adding animate class
    },
    routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(mymap);
```

And add the following CSS to your page:

```
path.leaflet-interactive.animate {
    stroke-dasharray: 1920;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1920;
    animation: dash 20s linear 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

The speed of the route is determined by the width of the `stroke-dasharray` and the `animation-speed`. In this example the route-animation will travel 1920px in 20 seconds. You can speed up or slow down the animation by adjusting either one of those CSS-values.

In this example I have also delayed the animation for 3 seconds, to give the map tiles a chance to load completely.

Comment: This is really great! I would love to know how to get an `onAnimationEnd` event trigger when the route has completed drawing

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there isn't a single way approach to achieve the outcome you are seeking. However, that are several ways that you may be able to have the change to adjust the speed of your route animation.

[Animate found route #101](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/101) is a suggestion from a user to add this feature -

> Add an option to animate the display of a new route, such that it grows from the start waypoint towards the destination. Which is similar to this -

https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00094/

Suggestions of how to achieve this animation includes:

> An option is to use D3 http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/. I'm using it in a sample that visualizes different driving times for our routing
>   http://ptv-logistics.github.io/fl-labs/
>
> A Leaflet plugin that does more or less exactly this: https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim
>
> that nearly works, however it requires [#191](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/191) and if you snakeIn the L.Routing.line by changing line 582 to read:
>   this._line.addTo(this._map).snakeIn();
>
> there is a bit of a problem as L.Routing.line is a layergroup that contains some stuff around the markers plus a polyline for each style assigned to the routeline, so they all get animated. It kind of needs to draw the first stuff fast, then the last style layer gets animated but I can't figure out how to do that.